# How to make textual object transparent for the mouse?

Tags: html, svg, click

Suppose I have a simple HTML page with embedded SVG object, which contains some text placed over an ellipse (the latter being a hyperlink):

```html
<html><body>
        <svg>
            <g>
                <a href="http://google.com">
                    <ellipse ry="30" rx="50" cy="100" cx="100" />
                </a>
                <text y="100" x="70" style="fill:#ef0000;font-size: 40">some text</text>
            </g>
        </svg>    
    </body></html>
```

Note that when the mouse is over the text, clicking does nothing: the textual object isn't transparent for the mouse clicking. How can I make the textual object transparent for the mouse without converting the whole text into a hyperlink?

Comment: why not just do a normal link that has the svg as a background (I guess that's what you're trying to achieve?), otherwise cancel your [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: @Pete I have several different hyperlinks in my SVG object with textual elements over every of them. I don't want to make the whole SVG object a single hyperlink.

Comment: @Pete Thank you, addition of `style="pointer-events: none;"` into the `text` tag works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution suggested in the comments by [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete) is to cancel [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) by setting `style="pointer-events: none;"`:

```html
<html><body>
        <svg>
            <g>
                <a href="http://google.com">
                    <ellipse ry="30" rx="50" cy="100" cx="100" />
                </a>
                <text y="100" x="70" style="pointer-events: none;fill:#ef0000;font-size: 40">some text</text>
            </g>
        </svg>    
    </body></html>
```